# Как открыть папку .git в gitkraken на удаленном сервере?

Tags: python, git, pycharm, gitkraken

Код пишу на локальной машине в Pycharm и средствами Pycharm-а организовал прямой деплой кода на сервер. Папка .git, сохраняющая изменения в проекте, находится в папке проекта на сервере.То есть пушу я изменения в gitlab с терминала сервера. Доступ до сервера происходит по SSH c подключенным VPN-ом. Пока работал с git-ом через терминал, все работало предсказуемо, как я того хотел.

Решил перейти на GUI клиент GitKraken и столкнулся с проблемой открытия проекта на сервере. Как это сделать?
Клонировать проект на локальную машину не хочу, с этим проблем не возникает. Но надо работать на сервере.
Операционная система Windows.

Comment: если у Вас Линукс, то удаленную папку можно примаунтить (mount) в локальную файловую систему и после этого кракен скорее всего заработает, правда будет не очень быстрым (если только сервер не лежит где то рядом). Я когда то пытался этого кракена использовать, но это было что то совсем вырвиглазное и немного платное.

Comment: для windows такое, как оказалось, также существует - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh  Но думаю, работать это будет очень и очень плохо.